# Bug in SSRS CreateFolder C# command?

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I think I've come across a bug in the CreateFolder command in the Reportingservices2010 SOAP API

The test scenario is I'm trying to create a folder (named **Sales Dashboard**) in the same Parent folder (lets say **Sales**) as a report also named **Sales Dashboard**.

The command completed with the "AlreadyExists" Exception when the folder does not already exist. It looks like the method isn't checking the catalog item type.

Here's my code:

```
 public static void createFolders(string targetURL, string folderName, string parentPath, string description, string visible)
    {
        //Build Authentication
        ReportingService2010 rs = new ReportingService2010();
        rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        rs.Url = targetURL;

        //Declare properties
        Property descriptionProp = new Property();
        Property visibleProp = new Property();
        Property[] props = new Property[2];

        descriptionProp.Name = "Description";
        descriptionProp.Value = description;
        visibleProp.Name = "Visible";
        visibleProp.Value = visible;
        props[0] = descriptionProp;
        props[1] = visibleProp;

        try
        {
            rs.CreateFolder(folderName, parentPath, props);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            if(ex.Message.Contains("AlreadyExists"))
            {
                //do nothing?
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

I wanted to see if I could contribute a fix but there's no GitHub repo for the C# SSRS stuff. Any thought's on a workaround?

Comment: Are you creating folders using the report manager?

Comment: @newGuy No, I'm creating the folder with the c# code above. The gui isn't affected. This looks like a bug in the RS 'CreateFolder' method

Comment: That's not a bug. That's perfectly normal. Those are *not* disk folders, they are *URLs*. You *can't* have the same URL refer to different types of resources. The url `Sales%20Dashboard` can't refer to a "folder" *and* a report at the same time. Just *don't* use the same names

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know they're not disk folders. The API also doesn't create content using urls. It checks for the existence of a catalog item before creating a new folder item. Folders and reports are both stored in the catalog table. The problem lies in that the check finds the name and reports the folder as existing without checking the catalog item type too.

Comment: @CPorteous how would it do that? When you request a URL there's no catalog or item type, only a URL. When you request `Sales%20Dashboard` what should the server return? The folder or the report object?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I clarified with riccardo-muti below that catalog items must have a unique name but to answer your question, the full URL for a report of folder differs in that reports call Report.aspx & folders call Folder.aspx as follows:
http://REPORTSERVER/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fSales%20Dashboard
and
http://REPORTSERVER/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fSales%20Dashboard&ViewMode=List

This URL format changes in SQL 2016 though.

Comment: @CPorteous what you posted here is the viewer's path, not the *resource's* path. That's not the link you'd use for example with `ReportViewer.aspx` to embed a report in a web page

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes I know. I don't think we're talking about the same thing here. I was using the SOAP API through C# to deploy content to SSRS. I am not embedding reports in web pages. Thanks for the contribution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is returning the correct error since this is a restriction of Reporting Services in general: items within the same folder must have unique names (regardless of item type).

Comment: Thanks Riccardo, I just tested this and I cannot create these manually either. I was under the impression this was possible. Thanks for the info.